# No replacing dots on StringToSlug

Tags: jquery

How would you not replace dots using String To Slug (http://leocaseiro.github.io/jQuery-Plugin-stringToSlug/). Currently if you use a dot on the string is replaced with a hyphen, but I would like for the slug to keep the dot, not to replace it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugged the issue with [`jQuery-Plugin-stringToSlug`](http://leocaseiro.github.io/jQuery-Plugin-stringToSlug/) plugin. It was found that there is a `getSlug( text, defaults.options );` function call happening from `jquery.stringtoslug.js` to `getSlug` method defined in `speakingurl.js`, which is a dependency of `jquery.stringtoslug.js`.

From the defenition of [`speakingurl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakingurl), under the [`usage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakingurl) section, there is a property called `mark` defined. This additionally allow chars: `"-", "_", ".", "!", "~", "*", "'", "(", ")"`. This is being fetched from `options` passed to `getSlug` method.

This options are passed from `jquery.stringtoslug.js`, which get its options from the function call `stringToSlug`

So you just have to set `mark: true` in your options.

**Working Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".basic-usage").stringToSlug({
    options: {
      mark: true
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/speakingurl/14.0.1/speakingurl.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-i1kgQZJBA3n0k1Ar2++6FKibz8fDlaDpZ8ZLKpCnypYznNL++R6FPxpKJP6NGwsO2sAzzX4x78XjiYrLtMWAfA=="
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="http://leocaseiro.github.io/jQuery-Plugin-stringToSlug/bower_components/jquery.stringtoslug/dist/jquery.stringtoslug.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="basic-usage" value="Replace the content of this input and check the preview text below!" />
<input type="text" id="permalink" />
```